# JavaScript reading multiple images and displaying them in different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var folder = "/img/gallery/";
$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                $("#galleryColumnOne").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
                $("#galleryColumnTwo").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
            } 
        });
    }
});
});
```

html:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapGalleryList" id="galleryColumnOne"></div>
<div class="wrapGalleryList" id="galleryColumnTwo"></div>
</body>
```

Target: to load full set of images from the folder and display them in div like: pic1 in galleryColumnOne, pic2 in galleryColumnTwo, etc..

Current state: each div display complete full set of images.

```
Edit: current state of the script generate:
<div1> pic1, pic2, pic3, etc. ;  <div2> pic1, pic2, pic3, etc.
should be:
<div1>pic1, pic3, pic5, etc.   ; <div2> pic2, pic4, pic6, etc.
```

Comment: just loop the result from the ajax callback

Comment: Can you describe which part you're having difficulty with? Given the code you've got, it seems you should be able to `var col=1` `col = col==1?2:1` `if (col==1) {} else {}`

Comment: @vincent-chinner I'm not pro dev. script I found and adapted it  to my situation. So, answer like "loop the result from the ajax callback" doesn't help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

So, final working script for my problem (thanks to @cars10m)is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var folder = "/img/gallery/";
$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {                   
                 $("#galleryColumn"+(i%2?'One':'Two')).append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
            } 
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a simple fix you could change your success function to something like this:

```
function (data) {
    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
        if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
            $("#galleryColumn"+(i%2?'One':'Two')).append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
        } 
    });
```

Although this will not be the quickest way of doing it and it would get "out of sync", when there are `<a>` links in `data` that do not point to images.

A better solution would be

```
function (data) { 
  var imgs=[];
  $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
    if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
      imgs.push(folder+val);
    }
  });
  $("#galleryColumnOne").append( "<img src='"+imgs.filter((v,i)=>i%2).join("'><img src='")+"'>" );
  $("#galleryColumnTwo").append( "<img src='"+imgs.filter((v,i)=>(i+1)%2).join("'><img src='")+"'>" );
}
```

My answer is not tested, therefore no guarantees. But the main idea is to get the `.append()` part out of the loop over the individual links. This way the (slow)`.append()` function will only be called once for each div. The contents (an HTML string) is prepared by using a fast `Array.filter()` and `.join()` operation.

There is one further point I would like to remark upon: You are using the expression

```
$(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {...});
```

to loop over `<a>` elements in your `data` HTML string. It works, as you have confirmed. I was puzzled, why you used this function, as its primary purpose is to *set* the `href` attribute of each matched element. After having had a closer look at the [jQuery .attr documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) it became clear to me that this is a valid way to directly access the chosen attribute value for all matched elements and do something with it. As long as the function does not return anything, the attribute will remain unchanged. However, the more *conventional* way of looping over DOM elements with jQuery would be:

```
$(data).find("a").each(function (i, elm) {...});
```

`elm` is the DOM element and you would get its `href` attribute with `elm.href`.

Comment: In the answer is a little bug but after fix it's working for me perfectly. Thank @cars10m you got my +1 however you won't see it as I'm still a newbie (and down-voted today for I don't know what)

Comment: Is it correct now? Otherwise, please let me know so I can fix my answer.

Comment: I forgot to add (sorry for that) in your first solution it's just missed bracket:                  $("#galleryColumn"+(i%2?'One':'Two')).append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it - but have a look at the second part of my answer too. It might be more reliable and faster.

Comment: second solution also working good! See http://arthanfurniture.co.uk/test%20jquery.html   . Thanks @cars10m.  BTW could you give me a clue as experienced user why my question was down-voted?

Comment: For me both version works ok  - that's mean I need some time to crack it ;-)

Comment: Why downvote? Probably because the contents of `data` is unknown to us. We could only guess that you received some valid HTML text with `<a>` elements in it. Next time try to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That helps! Do you think if I would add the link to working example on arthanfurniture.co.uk/test%20jquery.html  would change their opinion? I'm not sure it's quite save to be honest.

Comment: My practical goal in this small project is to have a simple website with picture gallery where adding new picture to gallery doesn't need any code modification.

Comment: It is usually better to keep everything self-contained within a single post. So, providing a sample `data` string would be best as external web sites might change or disappear over time.